# Scala: More Efficient Way to Filter a List and Create a Sequence of Futures

Tags: scala, future

Given a list of `Order` objects...

```
case class Order(val id: String, val orderType: Option[String])
case class Transaction (val id: String, ...)

val orders = List(Order(1, Some("sell")), Order(2, None), ...)
```

... I need to create a sequence of `Future`s for all those orders that have a type (i.e. `orderType` is defined):

```
val transactions: Seq[Future[Transaction]] = orders.filter(
  _.orderType.isDefined).map { case order =>
    trxService.findTransactions(order.id) // this returns a Future[Transaction]
  }
)
```

The code above first invokes `filter`, which creates a new `List` containing only orders with `orderType` set to `Some`, and then creates a sequence of `Future`s out of it. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can aggregate `filter` and `map` using `collect`

```
val transactions: Seq[Future[Transaction]] = orders.collect {
  case order if order.orderType.isDefined => trxService.findTransactions(order.id)
}
```